# How can I do a Update with slash on MySQL?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, sql-update, slash

Hello I try do a Update like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE info SET YES/NO = '$_POST[value]' WHERE ID = '$_POST[id]'";
```

I am getting this error:

> Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '/NO = 'YES' WHERE ID = '5'

I think this can be error from use SLASH on my database, If it is the problem how can i solve it?, thanks and i cant find any on google working for it.

Comment: You should not name columns like that, but by way of full disclosure you can try wrapping that column name in backticks like `\`YES/NO\`` I have never needed to do this but you can try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usualy, anything different than alphanumeric and underscore is not recommended.

Indeed, it is not a good practice to name a colomn like you did.

I will recommend you to rename the colomn `yes_no` otherwise, you will get the same error again, again and again.

Comment: This is not really an answer as it is more a advice which is better practice, but a workaround of the problem. Including RigsFolly comment at the question and some explanation why, would be better.